# Java - Most efficient random-access multi-threaded list

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, list, random

**Chosen List Structure:**

Synchronised LinkedList.

**Scenario:**

My program requires rendering some (rather computational) generated images in a grid. These images must update whenever some data value changes (on another thread), hence, I have a rendering queue to manage this.

The rendering queue is a synchronised LinkedList, where on a low-priority thread, it is constantly being iterated over to check if some render work needs doing. Since the images are based on all kinds of data, each of which could change independently, I needed some form of queue to combine changes.

Data tends to change in chunks, and so when a large batch comes through I see an imaginary line run down the area where it's re-rendering the tiles. To pretty this up a bit, I decided rather than rendering in standard order, I'd render them in a random order (to give a 'dissolve in/out' effect).

It looks lovely, but the only problem is, there is a notable different in the amount of time it takes to complete with this effect running.

**Problem:**

I've theorised a couple of reasons accessing this list randomly instead of iteratively would cause such a notable delay. Firstly, the Random number generator's nextInt method might take up a significant enough amount of time. Secondly, since it's a LinkedList, getting the nth item might also be significant when the size of the list is in the 4000s range.

Is there any other reason for this delay that I might have overlooked? Rather than using a random number generator, or even a linked list, how else might I efficiently achieve a random access & remove from a list? If you've read the scenario, perhaps you can think of another way I could go about this entirely?

**Requirements:**

- Multi-threaded addition to & modification of list.
- Random access & removal of items from list.
- Efficient operation, with large data sets & number of runs

Comment: the random lookups on the LinkedList could be costly. But in my experience / opinion, if you are using Random.nextInt to try to randomly generate all indexes between 0 and 5000 (or whatever) and you are dismissing the numbers when that index has already been processed, that could DEFINITELY be your issue

Comment: random access to a list is inherently racy unless you lock the whole list down, which is going to have perf ramifications

Comment: @ControlAltDel I'm not dismissing numbers, I'm removing the items from the list, so the list gets smaller. Which is why I'm using LinkedLists. Currently I'm generating a random number each time I pull another item from the list.

Comment: @yshavit what does racy mean? And what do you mean by lock the whole list down? It is synchronized.

Comment: Racy as in prone to race conditions -- explaining what those are is out of scope for a SO answer, let alone a comment. :) And by locking it down, I meant that you would need not just to synchronize it, but to surround all of the relevant actions within a `synchronized (list) { /* actions */ }` block.

Comment: I don't think I will suffer from problems with race conditions, since my only actions upon it are add, remove and a forgivably inaccurate size check (in the same method as the remove).

Comment: Using a linked list is almost never the right solution if you care about performance. I'd also recommend double buffering to solve the original problem.

Comment: What happens if the list has 10 elements, you randomly pick element 9 to render, then someone else comes in and removes that element after you've chosen `9` as the index but before you actually got around to getting it? `int idx = rand.nextInt(); /* another thread removes some elements, and then... */ list.get(idx);`

Comment: @yshavit that'll never happen. The only method that removes items from the list is the one responsible for rendering them, and also the one using nextInt.

Comment: @Voo Double buffering? I believe I'm already using double buffering? But you can still see the changes flowing down the screen when a large chunk of data comes in, and the renderqueue has to catch up with it.

Comment: if I understand your problem correctly, you have a number of "computing" threads enqueueing "data portions" into a queue, and a single "rendering" thread consuming from the queue and rendering. The fact that you say you see data rendering top-to-bottom seem to indicate that all computers react to changes applied top-to-bottom and that they perform comparable amount of work, for the most part preserving such top-to-bottom refresh. This is unexpected. can you provide more details on how the changes that would cause a computer to produce a new item in the queue?

Comment: you could address your problem by having the rendering thread dequeuing all items present in the queue up to MAX storing them in an ArrayList, then randomly selecting indices within the array. If the queue most of the time contains only 0 or 1 element, then you may want to have the renderer wait for some time (e.g.50ms) before looking at the queue again.

Comment: The reason it occurs top to bottom is because data comes in large batches. As a whole it's not like that, but is within large portions of the screen, since these changes are infrequent enough to be noticeable. Anywhere from 50 to 2000 at once, probably all in a span of a few milliseconds.

Comment: I may have just found an efficient solution to the problem myself, thanks to Roberto getting me to put the flow of data going on into clearer terms. 

First of all I noticed by only removing the first item from the list, I might as well use an ArrayList. What I then did was added a little variable called previousSize, which updates at every render. I then check if the current size is greater than previousSize plus some threshold, and if that's the case, I shuffle the list. Since the shuffle only happens as rarely as the updates, there's no noticeable performance hit!

Comment: represent each image as an actor, each update as a message, employ an actor library like Akka, and you'll be able render all images in parallel on a grid of machines.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `ArrayList` along with a couple of simple operations to implement this very efficiently.

- To insert, always insert new work at the end of the list (an amortized constant time operation).
- To extract a random piece of work, pick a random number `i`, swap the element at `i` with the element at the end of the list, and then extract and return that new last element.

Here's code (untested, uncompiled):

```
class RandomizedQueue<T> { 
  private final List<T> workItems = new ArrayList<>();
  private final Random random;

  RandomizedQueue(Random random) {
    this.random = random;
  }

  public synchronized void insert(T item) {
    workItems.add(item);
  }

  public synchronized T extract() {
    if (workItems.isEmpty()) {
      return null;  // or throw an exception
    }

    int pos = random.nextInt(workItems.size());
    int lastPos = workItems.size() - 1;
    T item = workItems.get(pos);
    workItems.set(pos, workItems.get(lastPos));
    return workItems.remove(lastPos);
  }
}
```

Comment: I do like the idea of swapping elements out, that way only the last element is ever removed. If my current solution (see comments on question) isn't as efficient as I like, I may try this.

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps use a PriorityQueue, and when adding things to this queue give each item a random priority.  The rendering can just always take the top element on the queue since it is randomized already.  Inserting at a "random" position in a PriorityQueue (or better put, with a random priority) is really fast.